# When should I quote CMake variable references?

Tags: variables, cmake, macros

I am writing CMake macros for the first time, and I have a hard time understanding how variables work. Most specifically, `${a}` seems to have a different meaning than `"${a}"`.

For example here: *[Passing a list to a CMake macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248749/passing-a-list-to-a-cmake-macro)*

When am I supposed to add quotes, and what are the bigger underlying principles?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Two principles of CMake you have to keep in mind:

1. CMake is a script language and arguments are evaluated after the variables are expanded
2. CMake differentiates between normal strings and list variables (strings with semicolon delimiters)

**Examples**

- `set(_my_text "A B C")` with `message("${_my_text}")` would give `A B C`
- `set(_my_list A B C)` with `message("${_my_list}")` would give `A;B;C`
- `set(_my_list "A" "B" "C")` with `message("${_my_list}")` would give `A;B;C`
- `set(_my_list "A" "B" "C")` with `message(${_my_list})` would give `ABC`

**Some Rules of Thumb**

There are some rules of thumb you should consider:

1. a) When your variable contains text - especially one that could contain semicolons - you should add quotes.

   *Reasoning*: A semicolon is a delimiter for list elements in CMake. So put quotes around a text that is supposed to be one (it works everywhere and for me personally looks better with CMake syntax highlighting)

   **EDIT:** Thanks for the hint from @schieferstapel

   b) To be more precise: A variable content with spaces that already had quotes does keep those quotes (imagine as it getting part of the variable's content). This works everywhere also unquoted (normal or user-defined function parameters) with the prominent exception of `if()` calls, where CMake re-interprets the content of unquoted variables after variable expansion (see also rule of thumb #3 and policy [CMP0054: Only interpret `if()` arguments as variables or keywords when unquoted](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html))

   **Examples:**

   - `set(_my_text "A B C")` with `message(${_my_text})` would also give `A B C`
   - `set(_my_text "A;B;C")` with `if (${_my_text} STREQUAL "A;B;C")` would give `if given arguments: "A" "B" "C" "STREQUAL" "A;B;C" Unknown arguments specified`
2. If your variable contains a list you normally don't add quotes.

   *Reasoning*: If you give something like a file list to an CMake command it normally expect a list of strings and not one string containing a list. The difference you can see e.g. in the [`foreach()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) command accepting `ITEMS` or `LISTS`.
3. `if()` statements are a special case where you normally don't even put the braces.

   *Reasoning*: A string could - after expansion - evaluate again to a variable name. To prevent this it's recommended to just name the variable whose content you want to compare (e.g. `if (_my_text STREQUAL "A B C")`).

---

**`COMMAND` Examples**

- `set(_my_text "A B C")` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${_my_text}"` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo "A B C"` on *VS/Windows*
  - call `cmake -E echo A\ B\ C` on *GCC/Ubuntu*
  - give `A B C`
- `set(_my_text "A B C")` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${_my_text}" VERBATIM` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo "A B C"` on *VS/Windows*
  - call `cmake -E echo "A B C"` on *GCC/Ubuntu*
  - give `A B C`
- `set(_my_list A B C)` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${_my_list}"` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo A;B;C`
  - give `A`, `B: command not found`, `C: command not found`
- `set(_my_list A B C)` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${_my_list}" VERBATIM` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo "A;B;C"`
  - give `A;B;C`
- `set(_my_list "A" "B" "C")` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${_my_list}" VERBATIM` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo "A;B;C"`
  - give `A;B;C`
- `set(_my_list "A" "B" "C")` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo ${_my_list}  VERBATIM` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo A B C`
  - give `A B C`
- `set(_my_list "A + B" "=" "C")` with `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo ${_my_list} VERBATIM` would

  - call `cmake.exe -E echo "A + B" = C`
  - give `A + B = C`

**Some Rules of Thumb with `add_custom_target()`/`add_custom_command()`/`execute_process()`**

There are some rules of thumb you should consider when you use variables in `COMMAND` calls:

1. a) Use quotes for the arguments that contain file paths (like the first argument containing the executable itself).

   *Reasoning*: It could contain spaces and could be reinterpreted as separate arguments to the `COMMAND` call

   b) See above, works also if the variable `set()` did include quotes.
2. Use quotes *only* if you want to concatenate something into a single parameter to be passed to executable that is called.

   *Reasoning*: A variable could contain a list of parameters which - when using quotes - won't be correctly extracted (semicolons instead of spaces)
3. Always add the `VERBATIM` option with `add_custom_target()`/`add_custom_command()`

   *Reasoning*: Otherwise the cross-platform behavior is undefined and you could get surprises with your quoted strings.

**References**

- [CMake: difference between ${} and "${}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582282/cmake-difference-between-and)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [Looping over a string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986392/looping-over-a-string-list)
- [CMake compare to empty string with STREQUAL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed)

For more information, see [this article by Craig Scott](https://crascit.com/2022/01/25/quoting-in-cmake/) (one of the maintainers of CMake), which discusses quoting considerations with lists and command arguments, generator expressions, and the `if()` command.

Comment: -1 because the reasoning behind the first rule of thumb #1 is wrong. If you pass a variable to a function (`func(${X})`, without quotes) and `X` contains spaces, `X` is still only one argument and does not get expanded/evaluated like you say. It would be too error-prone (like it is in e.g. POSIX shells) to quote every variable that may contain a path with spaces.

Comment: @schieferstapel Thanks for the hint. You're right and in that case there are no quotes necessary. I updated my answer accordingly. But I still think it would be necessary if I don't know if the variable may contain a list. And I've to check the `add_custom_command()` part again (thought I've tested it back then, but I'll double-check).

Comment: I still do not understand. Applying `arguments are evaluated after the variables are expanded` and `A variable content with spaces that already had quotes does keep those quotes` to the very first example, I would expect the `message` command to output text in at least single-double-quotes (or even double-double-quotes), but it does not print any.

Answer (score 1):

> When should I quote CMake variable references?

1. When you need to
2. When you feel like doing it and it technically makes no difference

---

> I have a hard time understanding how variables work. Most specifically, `${a}` seems to have a different meaning than `"${a}"`.

There are a couple of things you need to learn here with respect to the mechanics of CMake: How variable references work, how lists work, and how command arguments are handled.

There are a couple scenarios I can think of where this matters: command calls/invocations, and some specific commands which have special behaviour for arguments that are variable names, but are not evaluated variable references (Ex. `if(...)`).

#### For Command Calls in General

The docs for variable referencing can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references). Note that commands in CMake include functions and macros ([related docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-definitions)). TL;DR is that if you reference a non-existant variable without passing [`--warn-uninitialized`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-warn-uninitialized), CMake will evaluate the reference to an empty string. That's why the first `message` call above prints "foo: ", and why the first call to `set(foo ${foo} abc)` (which references `foo` in the second argument) will not error (as long as you don't use `--warn-uninitialized`)

In CMake, lists are just strings where each entry of the list is separated by a semicolon character. semicolons can be [escaped](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) with a backslash. You can find the full docs on lists [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists).

The docs for command arguments can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments).

- From the section on quoted arguments:

  > Quoted argument content consists of all text between opening and closing quotes. Both [Escape Sequences](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) and Variable References are evaluated. A quoted argument is always given to the command invocation as exactly one argument.
- From the section on unquoted arguments:

  > Unquoted argument content consists of all text in a contiguous block of allowed or escaped characters. Both Escape Sequences and Variable References are evaluated. The resulting value is divided in the same way Lists divide into elements. Each non-empty element is given to the command invocation as an argument. Therefore an unquoted argument may be given to a command invocation as zero or more arguments.

That's why I say "[quote variables] when you need to".

The rest of the deciding factor on what you need to quote to get the behaviour you want when invoking commands will depend on how the command's body handles the arguments it has been passed (after CMake has done un-escaping, variable reference evaluation, etc.). For those details, refer to the documentation for the specific command, or the documentation or implementation of the function/macro (see also the related docs for [function arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html#arguments), [macro arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#arguments), and [macro argument caveats](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#argument-caveats)).

#### For [the `if(...)` Command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#equal)

Okay, so why did I also say "*when you feel like doing it and it technically makes no difference*"? Because of the `if(...)` command's extra behaviours.

For any place in the signature of a `if(...)` "sub-command" you see "`<condition>`", refer to [the condition syntax documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax), which states:

> `if(<constant>)`
> True if the constant is `1`, `ON`, `YES`, `TRUE`, `Y`, or a non-zero number (including floating point numbers). False if the constant is `0`, `OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `N`, `IGNORE`, `NOTFOUND`, the empty string, or ends in the suffix `-NOTFOUND`. Named boolean constants are case-insensitive. If the argument is not one of these specific constants, it is treated as a variable or string (see Variable Expansion further below) and one of the following two forms applies.
>
> `if(<variable>)`
> True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise, including if the variable is undefined. Note that macro arguments are not variables. Environment Variables also cannot be tested this way, e.g. `if(ENV{some_var})` will always evaluate to false.
>
> `if(<string>)`
> A quoted string always evaluates to false unless:
>
> The string's value is one of the true constants, or
>
> Policy [`CMP0054`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html#policy:CMP0054) is not set to NEW and the string's value happens to be a variable name that is affected by [`CMP0054`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html#policy:CMP0054)'s behavior.

Also, many of the signatures / "sub-commands" of the `if(...)` command accept arguments of the form `<variable|string>`

Note that these are not talking about variable-*references*! Just variable names, which can lead to funky things that people might find unexpected, such as seen in [Numeric only variable name in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49605059/11107541).

If you want to be sure that something you intend to be a string in a `if(...)` command that will attempt to "auto-reference" variables by name in unquoted strings, then prevent that from happening by quoting it. So this covers both reasons: both "when you need to", and also "when you feel like doing it and it technically makes no difference" (I like to quote things that I intend to be strings in these contexts just for peace of mind).

Note that this behaviour isn't something necessarily special to `if(...)`. You can equally write a function that does this kind of thing (Ex. `${${ARGV0}}` (de-reference once to get the argument value, then de-reference again to treat the value as the name of another variable or additionally do a `if(DEFINED "${ARGV0}")` first to check if such a variable is defined first)). So if you want to be safe, always read docs (I'd just encourage reading docs in general).