# Turn list into arguments for cmake function

Tags: cmake

So let's say we have a CMake function called `func` which takes named arguments, say `NAMED1` and `NAMED2`. The first argument is mandatory and the second is optional. For example

```
func(NAMED1 foo NAMED2 optional)
```

Now I have a loop which needs to call this function `func` at each iteration, but depending on the current iteration I sometimes need to supply the optional value and sometimes not. So at each iteration I build a list of the arguments, say

```
list(APPEND args "NAMED1" "foo")
if (...something...)
    list(APPEND args "NAMED2" "optional")
endif()
```

So I have the `args` list now. As a string, it may look like

```
NAMED1;foo
```

or it may look like

```
NAMED1;foo;NAMED2;optional
```

So I thought to string replace the whole list with

```
string(REPLACE ";" " " args "${args}")
```

Then the resulting `args` will look like

```
NAMED1 foo NAMED2 optional
```

So I thought to pass this string to the function `func`, with

```
func("${args}")
```

But the problem now is that CMake thinks this is one big string, while it should interpret it as separate strings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just `func(${args})` without the quotes and without the need of replacing the `;` should work. I've been using this a lot of times in the past. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables).

Comment: Wow! You're right. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Just `func(${args})` without the quotes and without the need of replacing the `;` should work.

I've been using this a lot of times in the past (especially with forwarding "the rest of the parameters" with `${ARGN}`).

**References**

- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)