# cmake many INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES

Tags: cmake

I'm creating an imported target which wishes to expose two interface include directories:

```
list(APPEND LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "dir1")
list(APPEND LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "dir2")

add_library(lib SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(
    lib
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "something"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Unfortunately, there's an error: set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

If I try to set only the first directory, it works. Is there a way to set both? Or is the plural form of INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES simply ironic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the directory list in quotes

```
set_target_properties(
    lib
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "something"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
)
```

Otherwise the list is expanded again into parameters.

**References**

- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)