# Creating an archive with CMake at a location that I choose

Tags: shell, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to learn how to create archives with CMake. I wrote this piece of code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(hello)

message("Creating archieve in: " ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
message("Source dir is: " ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(hello main.cpp)


set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_custom_target(create_tar ALL COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfvz" "archieve.tgz")
add_dependencies(create_tar hello)
```

My project structure is like this:
I have a main folder in which I have a CMakeLists.txt, a main.cpp and a build folder. I go into build and run the cmake file above by 'cmake ..' and then make. My archive is created in the build folder but as you can see I have specified that I want it in the CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR which is along with the main, cmakelists and build folder not in the actual build folder.

Please explain to me why is that happening and how can I make the archive be created in the CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR and not CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR. Thanks.

Comment: `add_custom_target(create_tar ALL COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfvz" "archieve.tgz" WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`?

Comment: @Florian thank you! I see the 'WORKING_DIRECTORY' sets where the output of that command will be stored. Also please tell me if possible how can I specify which files to archieve. By default I can see that it archieves the files that are in the same folder as the cmake file. How can I specify for example only archive files in directory named "Dir"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

That would be `WORKING_DIRECTORY` parameter of the `add_custom_target()` command:

```
add_custom_target(
    create_tar ALL 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar cfvz "archieve.tgz" 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
```

The [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) is for changing the output directory of `add_library(... STATIC ...`)` targets.

And you can either run the `cmake -E tar` either the correct (sub-)directory by changing the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` accordingly (like `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dir"`) or give a list of files after `--` command line option (see [documentation of CMake Command Line Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode)).

Comment: Awesome. Just one final question(s) :D. What does the 'ALL' option that we pass to add_custom_target do? I don't quite understand what the documentation says. Also why do we need to specify ${CMAKE_COMAND} } -E and not just write 'tar blah blah'. Thanks.

Comment: Also: Why do we need to specify arguments for the tar command between ""? I noticed it works even if I write it normally like I would in the terminal like this: ' COMMAND tar cfvz archieve.tgz ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include '                           
Thanks.

Comment: @Kennedy The `ALL` option just means the build step is executed if you just call e.g. `make`. If you remove the `ALL` option you will need to explicitly trigger the build step by calling e.g.  `make create_tar`.

Comment: @Kennedy If you directly use `tar` then the `tar` program has to be on your PC and in your `PATH` environment. Since CMake is build for cross-platform support (that's where the `C` in its name is coming from) it is better to use CMake build in Command Line Mode and call `cmake -E tar` (works also on e.g. Windows).

Comment: @Kennedy The quotes are not needed for the parameters. So for more clarity I've removed them in my answer. About quoting in CMake see ["cmake: when to quote variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables).