# Numeric only variable name in CMake

Tags: cmake

What was the reason to allow **numeric only variable names** in CMake?
It makes the next code frustrative (if's condition becomes true):

```
set(1 3)
set(2 3)
if (1 EQUAL 2)
    MESSAGE( "hi there" )
endif()
```

And even more likely usage (if's condition becomes true also):

```
set(1 2)
... # later on, or even in the other file:
set(var1 1)
if (${var1} EQUAL 2)
    MESSAGE( "hi there" )
endif()
```

PS I understand why variable references without `${}` used inside [IF/WHILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html). But the possibility of numeric only variable names makes using IFs more error-prone...

Comment: The true reason is probably known to CMake developers only, so it is better to ask them directly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Not something I would have expected to be valid, although the docs do technically seem to allow it.

Comment: Please report this one in the CMake [bug tracker](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks for the link @CraigScott Bug reported: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17885

Comment: Things like this are why I always quote my literal arguments and use quote-wrapped explicit variable referencing in my `if()` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Brad King](https://gitlab.kitware.com/brad.king) at [CMake issue tracker](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17885#note_397902):

> For reference, variable names are arbitrary strings, e.g.

```
set(var "almost anything here")
set("${var}" value)
message(STATUS "${${var}}")
```

> Allowing numeric-only names is a side effect of that.
>
> Certainly they can be used in confusing ways.  Disallowing them, even
>   if only for if() evaluation, would require a policy.