# cmake - what does double quotes mean

Tags: cmake

In code below is from a CMakeLists.txt file. It builds and installs a library that uses cmake also. My question is what is the difference between `BINARY_DIR` AND `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, one uses double quotes and the other does not?

```
ExternalProject_Add(simple_amqp
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/simpleamqp-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/simpleamqp-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_EXE} ../simpleamqp-src 
  BUILD_COMMAND     ${MAKE_EXE} -j4
  INSTALL_COMMAND   sudo ${MAKE_EXE} install
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes serve to escape certain special characters in CMake, primarily the *semi-colon*. In CMake, the semi-colon acts as an argument separator even if it is produced by an expansion of a variable. In the (unlikely) case that the variable `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` contains a semi-colon, `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/simpleamqp-src` would be treated as two arguments, while `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/simpleamqp-src"` will be a single argument.

However, given that CMake's language is somewhat obscure and esoteric at times, it's perfectly possible the *real* explanation is closer to "some lines were copy-pasted from code which used quotes, and some were written by someone who thought they were [not] required, and ..."

---

To learn more about CMake syntax, quoting, and escaping, you can read its docs, particularly the [section about quoted arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument).