# CMake IF with multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, cmake, conditional-statements

How to make if function with multiple conditions? I know CMake support if with 2 conditions, but how to make more than 3?
I need something like this:

```
if(WIN32 OR APPLE OR IOS)
    set(LIBS)
endif()
```

Thanks

Comment: This should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: I checked on my Travis CI and it became failed build :(

Comment: It works for me. If `if` branch is not triggered, then none of `WIN32`, `APPLE` and `IOS` are set when you build your project.

Comment: What minimum version of CMake did you use? My project is set 2.8.12

Comment: Version of my CMake is 3.16. By setting `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)` it still works as expected. You tell about "failed build" but what **actually** do you observe? Why do you think that `if` is a reason of the problem? Have you got an error message about incorrect `if` command? Or do you expect `if` branch to be expected but it is not? Please, [edit] the **question post** and add details into it. Currently it is unclear what is your problem with the code provided. And without understanding your problem we simply cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone happen to stumble upon this question. Compound conditions are accepted in CMake.

But the particular conditional statement described in the question would fail to build, where it compares the CMake variable instead of referencing the value of the variables as shown below.

```
if( ${WIN32} OR ${APPLE} OR ${IOS} )
        message( STATUS "this works" )
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've written (`if(VAR_A OR VAR_B OR VAR_C)`) should work just fine.

CMake supports [`NOT`, `OR`, and `AND` for logical operators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#logic-operators) in `if()` command condition expressions, and you can enclose sub-expressions in `()` to control evaluation precedence/order.

Inside [condition expressions for the `if()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions), most *unquoted* strings that are not operands and which contain no variable references will be attempted to be resolved as if they were [variable references](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references) to a variable named by the string's content. That's why you don't *have* to write `if(${VAR_A} OR ${VAR_B} OR ${VAR_C})` or `if("${VAR_A}" OR "${VAR_B}" OR "${VAR_C}")`. But I usually do that anyway because I think it conveys intent more clearly (opinion). It can also help prevent other tricky points of confusion, such as [numbers being allowed as variable names](/q/49605059/11107541).

If you want further readings, see my answer to [When should I quote CMake variable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35847655/11107541).